# “Undefined reference" обобщенный класс

Tags: c++

Возможно ли реализовать шаблон в cpp, а не в h файле?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В общем случае, реализовывать шаблон вы можете в каком угодно файле, но помните, что [параметризованные] *определения* функций и классов шаблона *должны быть видны везде, где они используются* (специализируются, инстанциируются).

Если вы используете ваш шаблон только в одной единице трансляции (в одном `.cpp` файле) и больше нигде, то пожалуйста - реализуйте его в этом `.cpp` файле на здоровье.

А если ваш шаблон используется в нескольких разных единицах трансляции, то ваш `.cpp` файл все равно придется *включать* через `#include` везде, где он нужен, в точности как это делается с `.h` файлами.

По этой причине традиционно вся реализация шаблонного класса, включая определения его методов, помещается в `.h` файл. В `.cpp` файл идут только определения явно специализированных методов (explicit specialization), если таковые имеются.

(То есть ответ тот вопрос, который вы на самом деле пытались задать - нет, нельзя.)

Comment: Так сказать, алаверды :) Если такая реализация - в .cpp, и этот файл *включается* в разные файлы проекта - то в нем будет нельзя делать ничего, кроме того, что можно в заголовочном файле... Так что такой *включаемый* .cpp-файл *по сути* является включаемым h-файлом. Функциональность, так сказать, файлов - заголовочный, реализации - определяется *не расширением*, а *способом использования*.